# Couldn't compare a string with another one that is read from properties file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, properties-file

I'm automating a test of location selection. The options will be in the dropdown menu. There are three options(locations) in the dropdown menu. Depending on the location selected the data on the page will be changed accordingly. I'm trying to store the location in the properties and retrieve from it. The location in the properties file looks like:

```
location=UK
```

The code to retrieve the location property:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(f);
setLocation(prop.getProperty("location"));
```

When I try to print the location property, the correct value is getting displayed.

```
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("location")); //The value  UK is displayed
```

The setLocation() method code is:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(selectLocation));
selectLocation.click(); //now the dropdown will be displayed
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

if(location == "UK") {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ukLocation));
    action.moveToElement(ukLocation).click().build().perform();
    }
else if(location == "US") {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(usLocation));
        action.moveToElement(usLocation).click().build().perform();
    }else {
        System.out.println("didn't get the location");
    }
```

When I run the code

```
"didn't get the location"
```

is getting displayed. 
I've implemented the properties for the URL and it worked. Here I can get the location property and display it on the console but the problem is occurring at the string comparison. The setLocation() method works if I pass string as the location like:

```
setLocation("UK");
```

Comment: Post your code for `setLocation()`. My guess is that you aren't setting a variable `location` that is accessible in the scope where you test `if(location == "UK")`. To see this, add `System.out.println(location);` right before the `if`... it's likely `null` or "". BTW, when you post a question, you always want to add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: The code I've posted is the setLocation()'s. Yeah, I did actually put 'System.out.println(location) before if and it is printing the value which I've also mentioned in the description.

Comment: The code worked when using equals() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `.equals` rather `==`.

```
 if(location.equals("UK")) {
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Why the "==" operator didn't work?

Comment: Look up why to use `.equals()` vs `==` in Java. They don't mean the same thing.